# RequireJS Loading Error in IE11

Tags: javascript, requirejs, internet-explorer-11

It seems like the IE11 keeps executing JavaScript after load abort by user. I have a valid and working requireJS configuration with lots of modules.

When I open my Site and press the abort button (or klick at the home button to "reload") IE11 aborts all requireJS related async requests but keeps executing the requireJS Code (I figured it out with Debug and Network Panel). That ends in requireJS exceptions like

```
Script error for "main" http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

(Because the async request for main.js was aborted)

All other browsers seem to stop JS execution it the user aborts loading the page (which is imho the right behaviour). Is there a way to handle that behaviour with requireJS?

thanks for your help!